# How can I create an alice/bob (crypto) protocol diagram with arrows

Tags: amsmath, cryptocode

This image is taken from Boyd's book 'Protocols for Authentication and Key Establishment'. How can I create something similar? The arrows are important to me, since they allow to denote that User A sends something to User B.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have been able to do so far? Possibly providing a MWE (minimal working example) following the demands you find here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952. In the case above a simple `tabular` environment may suffice.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be using the [`cryptocode`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cryptocode) package.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[operators,sets]{cryptocode}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\pseudocodeblock{
\textbf{A} \<\< \textbf{B}
\\[0.1\baselineskip][\hline] \\[-0.5\baselineskip]
P = H_1(ID_a, ID_B, \pi) \\
r_A \in_R \ZZ_q \\
\dots \\
\< \sendmessageright*{m} \\
\<\< \text{Check } m \neq 0 \in G \\
\<\< \dots \\
\< \sendmessageleft*{t_B, k} \\
}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Very elementary approach: using table for organizing diagram, `amsmath` for expressions for "Alicw" and "Bob" and `tikz` for arrows between Alice and Bob:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                quotes}
\tikzset{auto,
                > = Straight Barb,
every path/.style = {semithick}
         }
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = {solid, 1pt},
                 colspec  = { Q[c,$] c Q[c,$] },
                 row{1-3} = {mode=text},
                 row{4-Z} = {rowsep=1ex}
                 } 
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    some text                           \\
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    some text                           \\
\SetCell[c=3]{l}    some text                           \\
A   &               &   B                               \\      
\begin{gathered}[b] 
    a=b\\
    c=d
\end{gathered}
    &   \tikz\draw[->]  (0,0) to ["$m$"]    (2.3,0);
                    &   \begin{gathered}[t]
                            expression = 1\\
                            expression = 2\\
                            expression = 3\\
                            expression = 4
                        \end{gathered}  \\
\bm{Z}=t_B^{r_A}
    &   \tikz\draw[<-]  (0,0) to ["$k'$"]    (2.3,0);
                    &   k=H_2(ID_A,ID_B,m,t_B,\bm{Z},\bm{P})          \\
\begin{gathered}[b]
    k\overset{?}{=}H_2(ID_A,ID_B,m,t_B,\bm{Z},\bm{P})\\
    k'=H_3(ID_A,ID_B,m,t_B,\bm{Z},\bm{P})\\
    \bm{K}=H_4(ID_A,ID_B,m,t_B,\bm{Z},\bm{P})
\end{gathered}
    &   \tikz\draw[->]  (0,0) to ["$m$"]    (2.3,0);
                    &   \begin{gathered}[t]
                            expression = 1\\
                            expression = 2\\
                            expression = 3
                        \end{gathered}  \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

The right content in cells you need to write yourself.

[image]